# How can I add assets folder when I create jar in vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar

I have my java project that I want to compile to jar file. But when I look inside the created jar file I can't see my assets folder.
My project structure looks like:

```
root/
+- src/
|  |
|  +- default-package/
|     |
|     +- .java files
|
+- assets/
```

It also trows an error when I try to run it: `Error: A JNI error has occured...`

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code you can click the right arrow after **JAVA PROJECTS** to compile the `jar` file.

[image]

This will generate the `jar` file in your project root directory.

[image]

In addition, your error may be caused by inconsistent versions of `java` and `javac`. You can check with the following two commands respectively.

```
javac -version
java -version
```

If not, please modify your environment variables to ensure that the `java` and `javac` versions are the same.